# Process not starting when I use more than two double quotes (\")

Tags: c++

I am writing a small C++ program, which involves starting a .exe process with many arguments, including sending paths which contain spaces, and hence require double quotes around the path. I have remembered to use the \" escape character.

I have tried lots of different ways of starting this process, and so have ended up at system(), simply to try to make the starting code as minimalist as possible.

I have this code:

```
string ExpandEnvironmentVariables(string input)
{
    char buffer[512];
    ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(input.c_str(), buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer));
    return buffer;
}
```

which works fine as far as I can tell.

Here is the code I am using to start the process (all the variables are std::string). This one works fine, however, it doesn't contain all the arguments I want to pass.

```
system(ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"" + path + "\" " + arg1 + " -c ").c_str());
```

This one doesn't work:

```
system(ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"" + path + "\" " + arg1 + " -c \"").c_str());
```

Notice the addition of the extra double quotes. It is not that the process errors, it is that the process never even starts up.

I am using Process Monitor to detect when the process is starting up, and no process.exe appears in it as soon as I add that extra double quotes into it. However, here is what I want to start the process with (which doesn't work either)

```
system(ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"" + path + "\" " + arg1 + " -c \"" + arg2 + "\"" + arg3 + arg4 + " " + arg5 + arg6 + " " + arg6 + "\\" + arg7).c_str());
```

I even tried to pair up the double quotes, but this doesn't work either:

```
system(ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"" + path + "\" " + arg1 + " -c \"test\"").c_str());
```

Finally, I was concerned about length. The addition of the third double quotes is what breaks it. However, before that, the length is 134 characters long. However, I want the actual starting routine to be 346 characters long. This isn't too long, is it???

I can debug the program, take the formatted string, and paste into Command Prompt, and the process starts perfectly. With those extra quotes, it is formatted perfectly. But I can't get it to start through C++!

Does anyone know what is going on here? It is driving me absolutely mad! Thank you so much for any help or advice you can offer.

Comment: Writing code that uses escape characters to pass escape characters to another process can get really tricky. Imagine a Makefile generating a code that calls `system`. Now imagine that shell invocation is a `printf`! `'\'` all over the place.

Comment: There must surely be a way to pass the arguments as an array!?! Something along the lines of execv would avoid the whole issue of escaping. Passing your commandline to launch as a single string is just a shoddy API if that's all Windows gives you.

Comment: Thank you both for your help as well, which helped me to end up at the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I will try and suggest you two workarounds:

1. instead of using `"` around your arguments, you could replace each space character by `\"`; to do the replacement correctly, you will have to specify `\\"` as a replacement string; try it at first without specifying any argument (only for the command name), and see if you can extend it;
2. write the entire command line to a batch file (it seems you are on Windows), then execute that file.

Check also this [post about Win32 double-quote escaping rules](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=764004).

Try this:

```
system(ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"" + path + "\" " + arg1 + " -c \\\"").c_str());
```

notice the 3 `\`: you want to pass the backslash to the shell (as if on the command line); if you only escape `"` once, the shell receives it as such, and interprets it as a string delimiter. what you want is that the shell receives it escaped, hence the double `\` in front of `\"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong personally, but I don't understand what... I have sent you my actual code, I have only renamed the variables, nothing else. I don't suppose you have any more ideas as to what a not-very-good programmer can do wrong!? Thanks a lot, though.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no other suggestion, apart from not relying on the process monitor: it will have a finite resolution, and if your process dies very quickly, it is possible that it will not detect it. Anyway, I will add an idea for a workaround in my answer...

Comment: In the end, I managed to get it to work using ShellExecute. I am not too sure why this one worked as opposed to the others - most likely me doing things wrong when using the others! Anyway, thank you so, so much for all of your help and advice, from which I learned a great deal, and ultimately led me to the solution. Thanks again :)